# Java validating a string equation

Tags: java

I am getting user input in a string and I need to validate that it is in this format "operand space operator space operand" or " 2 + 5 * 7 ^ 2". This is in java. I have researched for hours and have try regex and loops. I just can't figure out how to validate the string. Below is some of the code I have tried. I converted the string to chars in this example.

```
     for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
          char x = s.charAt(i);
             if(!(Character.isDigit(x) || x == '/' || x == '*' ||
                x == '+'|| x== '-' || x=='^' || x == '\n'))
                   throw new InValidCharacterExpression("Invalid expression. Please try again."); 
    }   
  }
```

Comment: They're comparing characters, not strings unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @tnw, this is comparing chars.  I think the answer will involve regex anyway.

Comment: @SteveSmith My mistake. Retracted close vote.

Comment: Did you do any [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=validate+mathematical+expression+syntax&oq=validate+mathematical+expression+syntax&aqs=chrome..69i57.6177j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?  [This](https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/40883-mathematical-expression-validation.html) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

How about searching for operator like +-*/ then split the string to two parts before operator and after in each part count amount of space then trim the result and convert it to number

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what expression you're looking for exactly to match, but here's a beginning (using RegEx)

```
public class ValidateExp {
    public static boolean validate(String s) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(-? ?\\d*[\\.,]?\\d+ ?[\\/\\+\\-\\*\\-\\^])+(-? ?\\d*[\\.,]?\\d+)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        if(m.find())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

It is optional whether or not you wanna separate the operators and operands with spaces:

- `10+10       true`
- `10 + 10     true`
- `10+ 10      true`
- `10 +        false`
- `10 *+ 10    false`
- `1 * 1^10    true`
- `1 * 1 ^ 10  true`

Comment: The expression would be something like "10 * 2 - 15 / 3 ^ 2"